# loop through an array to check for user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, properties

> Blockquote

How do i loop through this array and check if the user input exists in the array. If the user writes 'fanta' in the input field, i want to print 'fanta' and '27'"

```js
   const prisArr = [
        { vare: 'pepsi', pris: 30 },
        { vare: 'fanta', pris: 27 },
        { vare: 'escada', pris: 108 },
        { vare: 'dahls', pris: 69 },
        { vare: 'karsk', pris: 200 },
      ];
function vareSok() {
        for (let i = 0; i < prisArr.length; i++) {
          if (inpVare == prisArr[i]['vare']);
          document.getElementById(
            'resultat'
          ).innerHTML = `Varen med navn ${inpVare} koster ${pris} kroner!`;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="sok" />
    <button id="sjekkVare" onclick="vareSok()">Trykk her for å sjekke</button>
    <p id="resultat"></p>
    <script>
```

Comment: replace `${pris}` with `${prisArr[i].pris}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code. If user type "fanta" and click on button, the result is going to be "Varen med navn fanta koster 27 kroner!"

```js
const prisArr = [
    { vare: 'pepsi', pris: 30 },
    { vare: 'fanta', pris: 27 },
    { vare: 'escada', pris: 108 },
    { vare: 'dahls', pris: 69 },
    { vare: 'karsk', pris: 200 },
];
function vareSok() {
    let userInput = document.getElementById('sok').value
    for (let i = 0; i < prisArr.length; i++) {
        if (prisArr[i].vare === userInput) {
            document.getElementById(
                'resultat'
            ).innerHTML = `Varen med navn ${userInput} koster ${prisArr[i].pris} kroner!`;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="sok" />
  <button id="sjekkVare" onclick="vareSok()">Trykk her for å sjekke</button>
  <p id="resultat"></p>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const prisArr = [
{ vare: 'pepsi', pris: 30 },
{ vare: 'fanta', pris: 27 },
{ vare: 'escada', pris: 108 },
{ vare: 'dahls', pris: 69 },
{ vare: 'karsk', pris: 200 },
  ];

function vareSok() {
for (let i = 0; i < prisArr.length; i++) {
    if(prisArr[i].vare === inpVare) {
        document.getElementById(
            'resultat'
          ).innerHTML = `Varen med navn ${inpVare} koster 
${prisArr[i].pris} kroner!`;
    }
}
}
vareSok();
```

I think you're using the wrong syntax for getting the data. The if statement should be dot notation as you are referencing a key in an object. i is iterating over each object in the array. Then just change pris to prisArr[i].pris and it should work :)